# Accessing web API protected by Azure AD using a web app client

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

[image]Can someone please explain me how to access the protected web api using a web app client?

I am trying something mentioned here in the following link. But I am always getting

The provided access grant is invalid or malformed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn645542.aspx

Here is the code i am using for java

```
AuthenticationResult result = null;
    try {
        final Future<AuthenticationResult> resultFuture = context.acquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(
                code, new URI(redirectUri), new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret), RESOURCE_GRAPH_API, null);
        result = resultFuture.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        LOG.info("Failed to obtain access token: " + e.getMessage());

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {

    }
```

Comment: Does `redirectUri` match the URL defined in Azure AD?  Including the presence/absence of a trailing slash?  Sometimes that mismatch can produce this message.

Comment: updated my question with my usecase